# Filling a row with values

Tags: vba, excel

I started with VBA yesterday. Could this code be improved?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Column = 3 Then
        Call Modul1.AutoFill(target)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFill(activeCell As Range)
    Dim storedData As Range: Set storedData = GrabStoredData(activeCell.Value)
    If Not storedData Is Nothing Then
        Call FillRowWith(activeCell, storedData)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GrabStoredData(itemName As String) As Range
    Dim itemCell As Range
    Set itemCell = Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A:A").Find(what:=itemName, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not itemCell Is Nothing Then
        Set GrabStoredData = Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("B" & itemCell.row & ":G" & itemCell.row)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub FillRowWith(activeCell As Range, storedData As Range)
    Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 1 To 6
        Sheets("TargetSheet").Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.Column + counter).Value = storedData.Offset(0, counter - 1).Value
    Next counter
End Sub
```

We have a SourceSheet that works as the "Database". The SourceSheet has 7 columns, with the first one used to identify an item or order. The other 6 columns contain information.

Lets say we put an order in "TargetSheet" which already exists in "SourceSheet". It will find the order in "SourceSheet" and take the information in the 6 columns and replace 6 columns in "TargetSheet" with that information.

[This demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdjby.gif) should show it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

### `:`

Don't.

People read code downwards much better than they read across.
Almost all code everywhere operates under the convention "(at most) 1 statement/operation per line". Colons `:` are small and **very** easily missed. Just stick subsequent operations on newlines and you'll avoid a lot of confusion/errors down the line.

---

### `Call` is fully deprecated

It's not needed anymore and your code will run just fine without it. Assuming you name your methods well, dropping `Call` will also means your code reads better.

You will need to modify your calling syntax slightly though. When you have a `DoThing` `Sub`, this is valid syntax:

```
Call DoThing(Arg1, Arg2)
```

But this is not:

```
DoThing(Arg1, Arg2)
```

Functions get brackets. Subs do not. Like so:

```
Var = Function(Arg1, Arg2)
DoThing Arg1, Arg2
```

---

### Don't let renaming break your code

```
Call Modul1.AutoFill(target)

Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("B" & itemCell.row & ":G" & itemCell.row)
```

If that module gets renamed, or that sheet gets renamed, your code will break.

Fortunately there are easy solutions.

**1: Don't qualify your module references**

You shouldn't need to specify which module your subs are in. If you **do**, this implies wider problems with your code. If your methods are descriptively named and you don't do something horrible like having 2 identically-named methods in different modules, just call your method using its signature.

**2: Sheets have `Codenames`**

If you go to the properties window and select a `Worksheet`, there will be a `(name)` property. This is the sheet's `Codename`. By default, new sheets have codenames like `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` etc. A `Codename` is effectively a global worksheet variable that always refers to that sheet.

So, assuming you give "SourceSheet" a Codename of `sourceSheet` then your code can simply be:

```
sourceSheet.Range("B" & itemCell.row & ":G" & itemCell.row)
```

And now your users can name the sheets whatever they like and your code will still run fine.

---

### Be Explicit with your naming

Your method names are OK, but very, very ambiguous. `AutoFill`, `GrabStoredData`, `FillRowWith`, they all imply a level of generality that is at odds with what they actually do.

As a rule, names should be **descriptive**, then **unambiguous** and only then concise. Easy-To-Understand trumps Shorter-Name every time.

---

`GrabStoredData(itemName)`. Not a clue what that does in particular.

`GetRowRangeOfItemData(itemName)`. I immediately know **exactly** what that does. It's going to return a `Range` Object for a given item. This `Range` Object will be on a single row.

---

`AutoFill(Cell)`. Fill What? Where? With what?

`FillItemDetailsToRightOfCell(Cell)`. Takes about 0.2 seconds longer to read. Takes **much** less time to understand. Especially when someone else (or you in 6 months time) is coming back to this code with no memory of the internal workings.

---

`FillRowWith(Range, Cell)`. If I see that I'm going to assume it, well, **fills a row**. No Idea what those variables are, particularly.

`PasteRangeToRightOfCell(Range, Cell)`. Again, takes a fraction of a second longer to read, takes no time to understand **exactly** what's going on.

Comment: Thank you. I've made the necessary changes. Just one thing. I still have to use "Call" or it gives me an error.

Comment: @Robiow Ah yes. See edits.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you change something on the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) from within a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro (or any process called from within it) **always** disable the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx). Failure to temporarily halt event handling will try to get the Worksheet_Change to run on top of itself after being triggered by the new change on the worksheet.

Additionally, you should not turn off event handling without error control that will restore it if things go south.

**Target** can be a single cell or many cells (as in a paste operation to a group of cells. Typically, the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) is used to see if there is an overlap between the user's are of concern and whatever cell or cells that Target encompasses.

Naming your sub procedure the same as the [Range.AutoFill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) is not considered 'best practise'. Consider changing it to something like myAutoFill.

You seem to want a single cell for the parameter so I've cycled through all matching cells in the intersection of column C and Target in case there is more than a single cell. I'll try have a look later to see if a bulk operation is possible.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If not intersect(target, range("C:C")) is nothing Then
        on error goto bm_Safe_Exit:
        application.enableevents = false
        dim trgt as range
        for each trgt in intersect(target, range("C:C"))
            'should there be a check here to see if the value was simply deleted before proceeding?
            Modul1.AutoFill trgt     '<~~ should this be Module1 ?
        trgt
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

Comment: I've had another look at the companion sub procedures and in their current state, processing multiple matching cells one-by-one is the better method. However, using `activeCell` as the parameter's name (in two places) can only lead to confusion with the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) which is generally **not** target since a typed value typically moves off the cell that has been changed once [enter] has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider if your data for the target row is the same shape as the source row then i believe you can use the Value2 property. Assigning Value2 is quicker than iterating through each cell and assigning the Value property.

```
targetRow.Value2 = sourceRow.Value2
```

You can also use Value2 if your data is an array in the correct shape.